# return string with html from function to use in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am new to JSX/React, apologize upfront if this has been asked please refer me to the question. Trying to remove some inline code, I created a function which returns the value to display in the template/JSX, this works fine except when it needs to return a string + an element (Link element) the function looks like this:

```
let displayText = () => {
   let supportLink = <Link component={RouterLink} to={`/customers/${customer.id}/support`}>support</Link>
       
  return `We are unable to do something. If you have further questions, please contact our ${supportLink}`
  };
```

in practice this looks like

```
We are unable to do something. If you have further questions, please contact our [object, object]
```

How do I include the element in my string and have it display properly?

Comment: That's what would happen with *any* object, not just a React element: `\`Hello, ${{message: "world!"}}\`` is `"Hello, [object Object]"`, for example. Maybe you should return an element (e.g. using a `span` or `p`), rather than a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a template string so the `supportLink` is coerced to String, hence displaying `[object, object]`

You need to modify the return statement to return a `ReactElement` like this:

```
let displayText = () => {
   let supportLink = <Link component={RouterLink} to={`/customers/${customer.id}/support`}>support</Link>
       
  return (<>
    We are unable to do something. If you have further questions, please contact our {supportLink}
  </>)
};
```

Comment: This is great! Where can I read about this? Is it JS or JSX syntax?

Comment: Sorry, missed the info. It is JSX and that `<>` refers to `React.Fragment` more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html